# django sri does not recognize static files

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-staticfiles, django-filebrowser

i use django sri in my django project
and im add sri to installed_app
but sri not finding my static files

I try this

{% load sri %}
{% sri "main.js" %}
This working in localhost
but not working on cpanel host

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.